# Wordpress - Generate PDF of Post

Tags: php, function, wordpress, pdf-generation

I have searched all over the web for this, but cannot find the code (preferred) or plugin (not ideal) to do what I'm looking for:

### **QUESTION**

Is there a custom php function I can utilize OR place in my `functions.php` file, or a Wordpress plugin to use that will automatically generate a PDF of a Wordpress post (single.php only) and link in the post that a user can download?

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to do this just in PHP, that will work as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-to-pdf/

The Wordpress website has a handy plugins search page - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ :)

Comment: I searched existing Wordpress plugins but couldn't find anything that fitted exactly what I wanted (if using a plugin, I want LOTS of control). I'll check out your link.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider DOMPDF: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying: http://www.fpdf.org/.